# How to drive a speaker (earpiece) in an antique (vintage) phone (67 ohm)

Tags: amplifier, audio, speakers

I am using a small audio player board (DFPlayer Mini) that has a 3w audio amplifier built in.  I have hooked it up "as is" and it appears to work but has some intermittent static.  While it could be due to a loose wire, in the process of checking it out I noticed that the impedance is 67 ohm, not the typical 4 or 8 ohms.

Is there any circuitry I should add to protect the audio player and/or speaker?

[image]

Comment: In theory a matching transformer would be possible, but it's not a ratio you're likely to find.  This is probably not the source of your actual issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An audio amplifier will in most cases (modern boring designs, not tubes or esoteric amplifier topologies) not be harmed or have any difficulty with a *higher* impedance than typical. The output is approximately a voltage source, so a higher load impedance means less current flows. No big deal (unless it's too quiet).

If you want to be **sure** that you're using an appropriately designed amplifier for the application, choose one intended for headphones — impedances on the order of 67 Ω are entirely normal for headphones. Headphone amplifiers are also designed to suit the application by having lower noise (since you're putting your ear right up to the speaker).

Comment: Excellent, thanks Kevin!